# Raspberry PI, to google assistant error (--no such option --project-id'

Tags: linux, pi, google-assistant

recently I've tried to install the Google Assistant on my Raspberry pi 4 (2GB)
And I'm almost finished but stuck on the option 'Error: no such option; --project-id'
Can someone help me out?, before this it was 'asyntax.error' now its this..

pip install -U tenacity
, helped fix the first problem
Now 'no such option; --project-id'

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and enter all necessary commands you ran to reproduce the problem? See [ask].